# Where are the Aperture Science Logos?

Tags: half-life

I'm replaying the original Half-Life on Steam. I seem to remember there being Aperture Science logos on the laser equipment that you pass on the way down to the containment chamber at the start of the game.

However they no longer appear to be there. Am I just mis-remembering or did Valve remove them from the Steam version at some point?

Where are the Aperture Science logos in Half-Life?

Comment: Half-life 2 Episode 2 had it on the [Borealis](https://half-life.fandom.com/wiki/Borealis?file=Borealis_mini_episode_two.jpg).  Maybe that's it?

Comment: I think I am going to have to dig out my original CD and check

Comment: There is also a remake titled [Black Mesa](https://store.steampowered.com/app/362890/Black_Mesa/) that may have some Aperature logos in it.

Comment: @Batophobia you might be right about it being Black Mesa. I must have played it when it was still a free community project.

Comment: Half Life 1 (1998) released 9 years before Portal (2007). I'd be surprised if the Aperture logo was in the game

Answer (score 5):

I can't remember encountering the name or logo at any point in the first Half-Life, nor any (unused) texture in the Hammer Editor referencing it (I rechecked to be sure).

According to [the Fandom wiki entry on Aperture Science](https://half-life.fandom.com/wiki/Aperture_Science), **there is [no appearance in Half-Life](https://half-life.fandom.com/wiki/Aperture_Science#List_of_appearances)**.
This is corroborated by the [Combine OverWiki](https://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Aperture_Science#List_of_appearances).